# 404 on Nginx running on docker (uwsgi)

Tags: nginx, flask, docker, uwsgi

I have been battling with this and can't get my head around it.

I have a simple Dockerfile which works and I use **supervisord** as CMD to start nginx and uwsgi. And it does the job but I get back 404. So what I do is to instead **start the docker with `/bin/bash` and manually start things and debug**, e.g.:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 8095:80  myimage /bin/bash
```

So this is my nginx conf (in sites-available and then a link in sites-enabled):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/WikiRockWord2Vec/WikiRockWord2Vec.sock;
    }
}
```

and this is my uwsgi ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5


socket = /WikiRockWord2Vec/WikiRockWord2Vec.sock
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
uid = www-data

die-on-term = true
```

Socket does get created and I have changed permission to 777 to make sure all nginx has access to. But it seems nginx does not send to upstream anyway.

Browsing to localhost:8095 brings the nginx homepage find but any other route returns 404. **Nginx error log is empty**.

*I have confirmed that nginx **reads the .conf** (by adding spelling mistake and see the error in the nginx log) but changing socket location has no impact as if it does not even care about that section.* **In similar cases on my ubuntu box when the sock file does not exist or there is a permission issue, I get 502 and some hint in the logs.** **But here I get nothing, as if UWSGI NOT CONFIGURED AGAINST NGINX.**

I am lost, can you please help? Am I missing module configuration in nginx (similar to apache)? I am new to nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 is probably because your `nginx conf` file's `server` block incorrect, i think is because your `server_name` part.

so here is my modified version, you can check if it working

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///WikiRockWord2Vec/WikiRockWord2Vec.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to remove the default conf since it was conflicting but that was easy compared to this

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Nginx, uWSGI, Supervisord, etc, (and just for a Flask application) could be difficult, so I made a public (and open source) Docker image with all the bells and whistles that you can use to build a Python Flask web application.

It has uWSGI for running the application, Nginx to serve HTTP and Supervisord to control them, so you don't have to learn how to install and configure all those to build your Python Flask web app.

It seems like uWSGI with Nginx is one of the more robust (and with great performance) ways to deploy a Python web app. Here are the benchmarks: http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers.

There are even some template projects you can use to bootstrap your own. And also, you don't have to clone the full project or something, you can just use it as a base image.

Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/

GitHub: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

Comment: shouldn't be 1 docker 1 service?, in your case you have 1 docker and several services running

Comment: @EsseTi 

There's the rule of thumb that you should have "one process per container".

That helps, for example, isolating an app and its database in different containers.

But if you want to have a "micro-services" approach you may want to have more than one process in one container if they are all related to the same "service", and you may want to include your Flask code, uWSGI and Nginx in the same container (and maybe run another container with your database).

Check this: https://valdhaus.co/writings/docker-misconceptions/